# PHP outputs content after a "->"

Tags: php

I try to post a form to trello via their api.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once '/src/Trello/trello.php';
    $key = '[KEY]';
    $token = '[TOKEN]';
    $trello = new \Trello\Trello($key, null, $token);

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $desc = $_POST['content'];
    $fileSource = $_POST['file'];

    Trello->post("cards", { name: $title, desc: $desc, idList:"54f882603b3b0af795078283", pos: "top", fileSource: $file});
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
    <title>php form2trello</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">        
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>php form2trello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form id="trello" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="eMail" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="form-control" required/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <textarea name="content" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Content" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="file" name="attachment" value="1" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(I removed [KEY] and [TOKEN] for security purpose)

Here is a demo page:
http://area51.zoker.me/test/php/output/

As you can see at the very beginning, there is just a output `post("cards", { name: $title, desc: $desc, idList:"54f882603b3b0af795078283", pos: "top", fileSource: $file});?>`

Why does php output these strings?
How can I avoid it doing this?

Comment: If you do a "view source" you'll see the entirety of your PHP script; ie your webserver isn't configured to execute PHP

Comment: Looks like your http server is not setup to interpret php.

Comment: I'd also recommend changing your real KEY and TOKEN, because those secrets are now public domain

Comment: Its a normal webhosting package, wordpress installations work well there...

Comment: That's as may be, but the code is being displayed, not executed.... and your secret key and token are clearly visible to a "view source" and equally visible to google searches now as well

Comment: I removed the key and the token from that page, just forgot that :P
I will ask my hoster, why this does not work :)

Comment: Does the file this code is on have the `.php` extension instead of `.html` or `.htm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the source of the page you linked, it appears that the whole php code is included in the HTML page, rather than being executed. So it treats the `<?php` as an opening html tag and the `Trello->` as a closing tag. The rest gets printed in the page as normal html text.

Also, a comment asked if this is an `.html`/`.htm` or `.php` page. It looks like an `.html` page (I tried `index.php` and got a `404`, tried with `index.html` and it loaded), so the php code won't get parsed.

Comment: When I add the file index.php, I got a blank page (same content as index.html):
http://area51.zoker.me/test/php/output/index.php

Comment: @Zoker have you made sure you don't have any errors in your php? Try running it piece by piece to figure out where it goes wrong.

Comment: I have to delete the require_once, $trello and Trello-> line. This is the only way to get the content displayed. Is there any error in this part? I cant find one (but Im no php expert :/ )

Comment: @Zoker are the paths correct? And to be honest I don't really understand why you call the constructor like that: `new \Trello\Trello($key, null, $token);`

Comment: I got that line from the trello framework: http://code.mattzuba.com/php-trello and I found this in the error log; http://pastebin.com/chSb5DzJ

Comment: @Zoker Yeah.. change `Trello->post` with `$trello->post` on line 11 and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Yea that seems working, thanks :) The hole form does not post to trello, but I try to ask the author of the framework, if he can help me. Any idea how I can track the response from the api?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72507/discussion-between-kostas-drk-and-zoker).

Answer (score 1):

Rename `index.html` to `index.php`,

This line

```
Trello->post("cards", { name: $title, desc: $desc, idList:"54f882603b3b0af795078283", pos: "top", fileSource: $file});
```

should read more or less like this:

```
$trello->post("cards", json_encode([ 'name'=> $title, 'desc' => $desc, 'idList' => "54f882603b3b0af795078283", 'pos' => "top", 'fileSource' => $file ]));
```

Comment: But when I add the same file named index.php, I just got a blank page:
http://area51.zoker.me/test/php/output/index.php